# Minikube Running exception when try to enable RBAC in Local PC

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, minikube, rbac

**I Try to Run this command to start minikube:**

```sh
minikube start \
         --extra-config=apiserver.Authorization.Mode=RBAC \
         --extra-config=kubelet.cgroup-driver=systemd \
         --driver=docker
```

**And Also Try,**

```sh
minikube start \
         --extra-config=apiserver.Authorization.Mode=RBAC \
         --driver=docker
```

But It's giving me errors.
How can I solve this problem...........?

**errr like:**

```sh
stderr:
    [WARNING IsDockerSystemdCheck]: detected "cgroupfs" as the Docker cgroup driver. The recommended driver is "systemd". Please follow the guide at https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/cri/
    [WARNING Swap]: running with swap on is not supported. Please disable swap
    [WARNING SystemVerification]: this Docker version is not on the list of validated versions: 20.10.7. Latest validated version: 19.03
    [WARNING SystemVerification]: failed to parse kernel config: unable to load kernel module: "configs", output: "modprobe: FATAL: Module configs not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-84-generic\n", err: exit status 1
    [WARNING Service-Kubelet]: kubelet service is not enabled, please run 'systemctl enable kubelet.service'
error execution phase wait-control-plane: couldn't initialize a Kubernetes cluster
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to start minikube with `--bootstrapper=kubeadm` and this will enable RBAC for you

```sh
# Start minikube with kubeadm (Its the default so it's not mandatory)
minikube start --bootstrapper=kubeadm

# Create the default role binding [kube-system:default]
kubectl create clusterrolebinding \
        add-on-cluster-admin \
        --clusterrole=cluster-admin \
        --serviceaccount=kube-system:default
```